# dist-upgrade not working properly with padoka's PPA

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

After installing [padoka's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa) on Kubuntu 16.10, whenever I run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, I get the following:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libomxil-bellagio-bin:i386 libomxil-bellagio0:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvmc1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
```

If I run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove the automatically installed packages, they just get automatically reinstalled upon the next `sudo apt dist-upgrade` (and immediately reappear in that list).

Also, I'm concerned that those two packages are being kept back instead of upgrading. It looks like the newest version of `mesa-vdpau-drivers` needs `libomxil-bellagio0` and `mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386` needs `libomxil-bellagio0:i386`, but `libomxil-bellagio0` and `libomxil-bellagio0:i386` conflict with each other.

My package lists and system are entirely up-to-date with the exception of the above. Also, this has been going on for a few weeks. How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: Since I asked this question (although still long ago at this point), I did a clean install of a newer Ubuntu version for unrelated reasons. I don't have this problem on the newer Ubuntu, so I'm voting to close my own question since 16.10 is EOL.